# Choosing a conserved quantity to obtain a symmety via Noether's Inverse Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Noether's Inverse Theorem says that there must be a symmetry $\delta q^{i}$ given a conserved quantity $C$.

$$\delta q^{i}=\epsilon W^{ij}\frac{\partial C}{\partial q^{j}},$$

where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary constant and $W^{ij}$ is the Hessian of the Lagrangian.

Basically, one can guess some $C$ to obtain $\delta q^{i}$ from this equation, but usually one knows from the Lagrangian which $C$ is suitable for doing this.

**My question is:** Is there a way of knowing what is not a conserved quantity for the system? Or a way to make this equation fail given a $C$?

---

In particular, I am working with the Lagrangian:

$$L=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)-V(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})-\frac{m}{2}[(\dot{x}y-\dot{y}x)\omega^{2}+\omega^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})]$$

where $V$ is a derivable function.

I found that the energy $E$ gives a specific symmetry. But, I am afraid of inserting the angular momentum and find that there is another symmetry, and actually afraid that anything that I would insert in the equation would give more symmetries... I think there should be something that tells me that some of those are actually not symmetries.

Comment: That doesn't look like any Noether's theorem formula that I've ever seen...

Comment: Looks like maybe axial symmetry around z. You can try. Not obvious to me if the xy dot- yxdot is symmetric, and I probably need to do some more thinking. Try the rotation around z. I'll look if any procedure other than guessing - and easier by trying the symmetry, eg rotation around one axis, than the conserved quantity, $L_z$

Comment: @tparker my teacher called it "Noether's Inverse Theorem" in the sense that you can obtain a symmetry from a conserved quantity... (I haven't seen it anywhere in the internet too)

Comment: Ok, if you can guess C. I just think that's harder, but you could try $L_z$. I'm not sure it'll work, maybe the X dot y etc term needs to be square for that, can't think on my feet. I think the other terms are axially symmetric, but I could be wrong. Need to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best/most systematic to discuss the inverse [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) in the context of Hamiltonian formalism (as opposed to Lagrangian formalism), cf.  e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE posts, which also provide Lagrangian counterexamples. Therefore OP's Lagrangian of the form
$$ L~=~\frac{m}{2}(\dot{q}_x^2+\dot{q}_y^2+\dot{q}_z^2)+B(\dot{q}_yq_x-\dot{q}_xq_y)-V(q) $$
should preferably first be [Legendre transformed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) into the corresponding Hamiltonian

$$ H~=~\frac{1}{2m}\left( \left(p_x +Bq_y \right)^2+\left(p_y -Bq_x \right)^2 +p_z^2 \right) + V(q). $$

Then as shown in Statement 3 in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69277/2451), we have an inverse Noether's theorem: If $Q=Q(q,p,t)$ is a [constant of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion), then the corresponding [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) 
$$-X_Q~:=~ -\{Q,\cdot \} ~=~\{\cdot ,Q\}$$ 
will generate a quasisymmetry of the phase space action.