# Does Noether's theorem work the other way round too?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry

[Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) states that symmetries are accompanied by a conservation law. So for example, if a system is symmetric under translation in space momentum is conserved; or if a system is symmetric under rotation, angular momentum is conserved.

Now a translation in space can be achieved by applying an infinite number of times an infinitesimal generator (which contains the momentum operator) from the initial point to the point you want to reach.

The same can be said in the case of finite a rotation: it is achieved by applying the infinitesimal generator (which contains the angular momentum operator) an infinite number of times.

Or if the system is symmetric in time, energy is conserved (what is the infinitesimal generator in this case? I guess the energy is part it).

Concerning the symmetries of space and time (which form a four-vector) does the inverse also hold? So if a system is symmetric under a translation in energy-momentum space does that imply that time and space are conserved, which is obviously the case, but can we express that in this way?

Comment: 1. The title question about an inverse of Noether's theorem is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/50583. 2. Your actual question seems to be not about an inverse to Noether's theorem, but about "translations in energy-momentum space". What is "energy-momentum space"? The setting of Noether's theorem is either Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics, and neither of these has such a space, so what are you thinking of here? If you are simply thinking of a covariant phase space, then that would just be an application of the usual Hamiltonian Noether's theorem, no?

Comment: To reopen this question (v1), formulate the actually and title question more carefully than just _Does it work the other way around?,_ which is likely to be misunderstood as a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451

Answer (score 1):

There is a bijection of conservation laws with continuous (but not discrete) symmetries. Yes, it works both ways. In fact, physicists usually deduce conservation laws from symmetries, not the reverse.