# Are first Integrals the same in Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

A first integral in Lagrangian formalism is defined as a function which is constant along the solutions $(q,\dot{q})$ where $q$ are the generalized coordinates; while a first integral in Hamiltonian formalism is a function which is constant along the solutions $(q,p)$ where $p$ are the generalized momenta.

Do first integrals in Lagrangian formalism remain first integral in Hamiltonian formalism and viceversa? i.e do functions constant along solutions of Lagrange's Equations $(q,\dot{q}$ remain constant along solutions of Hamilton's Equations $(q,p)$?

At first guess I'd say yes, but I can't exactly think why; maybe it's just enough to apply the transformation rules?

$
q(q,\dot{q}) = q\\
p(q,\dot{q}) = \frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q})}{\partial\dot{q}}
$

It's just a doubt I had while studying the different versions of Noether's theorem in the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian case, since we are using *very* different coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352393/2451

Comment: Unfortunately it goes beyond what I studied, I'm not sure I fully understand the contents of the answers. Hopefully someone is able to explain in more elementary terms.