# Can there be conservation laws without a corresponding symmetry?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Noether's theorem implies that if there is a continuous symmetry in the Lagrangian of a system, this necessarily implies a corresponding conservation law. But does the theorem also imply the reverse? Is it possible for a system that obeys a conservation law to not have a corresponding symmetry in its Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451