# What are "on-shell" and "off-shell" conditions in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am familiar with Goldstein-level mechanics. However, here in this site, many sophisticated users use the term "on-shell" and "off-shell" conditions too often, which I did not encounter in Goldstein or similar. Can somebody explain the meaning of these two terms in classical mechanics through an example?

Comment: Did you encounter those terms used in the context of classical mechanics?

Comment: Yes. See Qmechanic's answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490018/

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I know what is on-shell and off-shell particles. Your Wikipedia link does not help.