# On-shell condition in Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology

Which is the on-shell condition in classical mechanics? I mean in QFT we use to tell about external particle state as to be in a on-shell condition which means that these particles have to statisfy the mass shell relation $p^2=m^2$. But in Classical Mechanics which is the shell? I figured out that on-shell condition means that the particle must follow the EOM, so I guess that shell condition has to be $\ddot{q}(t)=0$, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. "On-shell" means a configuration that satisfies the classical equations of motion.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491018/2451