# Are the basins of attraction of two static gravitational sources two half-planes?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Consider the following setup:

Two massive bodies of mass $M$ are **fixed** at the positions $\vec{A}=(d, 0)$ and $\vec{B}=(-d, 0)$.
[image: setup]

Now imagine a test particle $p$ with initial position $\vec{r}_0=(x_0,y_0)$ and initial velocity $\vec{v}_0=(0,0)$. Its position $\vec{r}(t)=\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$ will change over time under the influence of the gravitational potential. If the test particles trajectory goes through $A$ (or $B$) the initial position $\vec{r}_0$ lies in the basin of attraction of the mass at point $A$ (or $B$).

### *Question*: Does $x_0 \gt 0$ imply that $p$ will eventually come arbitrarily close to $A$ (**and not** $B$)?

### *Or simpler yet*: Does $x_0 \gt 0$ imply that $x(t)\gt0$ for all $t$?

---

NOTE: This problem is known as a special case of Euler's three-body problem. It is discussed in great detail in "Integrable Systems in Celestial Mechanics" by Diarmuid Ó Mathúna, where the equations of motion are given in closed form using Jacobi elliptic functions, by transforming to what Mathúna calls "Louiville coordinates". I am currently working through the derivation of this, but as it is very technical, it will take me some time. It is still possible, that the question may be answered without the explicit equations of motion.

---

Background:

I'm currently working on a (2 dimensional) simulation of gravity which visualizes gravitational basins of attraction.

The simulation works as follows:

$n$ massive bodies are given an intial position. They are treated as **static** and will never change position during the simulation. Each body is also given a unique color property (for visualization purposes later).

Next, the simulation space is filled with particles. Their initial velocity is set to zero. Their trajectories are calculated via numerical integration.

When a collision between a particle and one of the massive bodies is detected, the initial position of the particle is assumed to lie in the basin of attraction of that body (with which it collided). A collision occurs when the distance to a body is below a certain threshold. The initial position of the particle is then marked in the color of the planet it collided with.

---

In general the resulting pictures are very complex.

[image: Example of basins of attraction of many bodies]

Here are some more examples: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOld5.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVqMd.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WHI0.png), [4*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ6MK.png)

As you can see the basins are generally fractals.

Yet, when I simulate the above described setup, where $n=2$ and the masses of the two bodies are the same, the following picture is produced.

[image: basins for two bodies]

Where blue pixels represent initial positions in the basin of attraction of the mass at point $A$, red pixels those in the basin of the mass at point $B$ and black pixels in neither. (A thin strip of black pixels lie on the line $x=0$, where they oscillate around the origin)

### The picture is clearly devided into two half planes, yet I can not explain why. Any help explaining this fact would be much appreciated.

---

I tried solving the problem analytically using Lagrange's equations of the second kind. I set:
$$T=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$$
$$V=-GM m\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-d)^2+y^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+d)^2+y^2}}\right]$$
And obtained the following equations of motion:
$$\ddot{x} = -GM\left[\frac{x-d}{\left((x-d)^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{x+d}{\left((x+d)^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right]$$
$$\ddot{y} = -GM\left[\frac{y}{\left((x-d)^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{y}{\left((x+d)^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right]$$

Where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of the particle, $m$ the mass of the particle, $M$ the mass of the massive bodies and $d$ the distance (in the $x$-direction) from the origin of the massive bodies.

I converted this into a system of four first-order differential equations and tried solving it using Maple's *dsolve*, but it's been stuck *Evaluating* for two hours now, so I don't think it's going to finish...

---

Another thing I tried is showing that a particle on one side will never have enough potential Energy to ever cross the line $x=0$, but then I considered the starting location $\vec{r}_0=(2d,y_0)$ with arbitrary $y_0$.
$$V((2d,y_0))=-GMm\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2 + y_0^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{9d^2 + y_0^2}}\right]$$
Then I could easily show that there exists a point on the line $x=0$ that has less potential, therefore I imagined the particle could reach that point and still have "kinetic energy leftover" to cross the line. One such point would be $\vec{r}_1=(0,y_0)$, since:
$$V((0,y_0))=-GMm\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2 + y_0^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2 + y_0^2}}\right]$$
From which it became evident that 
$$V((2d,y_0))\gt V((0,y_0))$$
A flaw in this argument could be, that the particle could never reach $\vec{r}_1$ (or any point on $x=0$ which has less potential). Another fact I can not prove.

Comment: I would guess that the version of the problem where the sources orbit each other has been studied, but since this version is unphysical for astronomical bodies, maybe it hasn't been. Yours would be like the physical version in the rotating frame, but with the centrifugal and Coriolis forces turned off. *This went against my intuition, as I assumed chaotic effects would not appear until I added a third body.* You do have three bodies: the two static sources, and the test particle.

Comment: @Ben Crowell: I assumed the velocity of the two bodies was negligible when compared to those of the test particles. After your rewording of the problem in your comment, I can see how that "simplification" was not one I can make. Thank you for clarifying.
Although the initial question still interests me.

Comment: Is it 3D or 2D and what is the size of the integration region?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : It's 2D and I'm not sure what you mean by "integration region". The initial positions of the two bodies are (-50, 0) and (+50,0). Particles are spread around a region which is [-250,250]x[-250,250]. Although I believe you have to scale all values by 1/G since I assume the gravitational constant to be 1.
Not sure if that helps clarify.

Comment: Why did you take (-50.,0) and (50,0)? You could take (-0.5,0) and (0.5,0)) and the integration region (-10,10) x (-10,10).

Comment: @AlexTrounev because my window is 500 pixels squared in size, so it was the most natural. What would scaling the region do for me? Are floating point numbers more accurate in that region? Is Runge-Kutta more accurate in that region? Please elaborate.

Comment: The initial velocity of test particles is 0? Then potential energy should tell you the basins of attraction ares two half planes. Could this be cumulative round off error? RK is stable, but do you have a bug?

Comment: @mmesser314 If you can prove that the basins of attraction are in fact two half-planes, then this is an answer to my question. As it stands your comment seems to be a restating of my question.

Comment: It was just an intuitive thought. And on second thought, I am not sure I believe it. If you start far from the massive bodies near the plane, you have lots of potential energy. When the test particle gets close to the masses, it might well have enough kinetic energy to cross the plane. So your RK integration might be right. But I cannot account for the difference between your two methods.

Comment: I have always assumed the basins are divided by a plane, so my advice would be to dig deeper into the integration.  In particular, play with the integration parameters.  A "real" effect will stay around as you change integration times and such.  A bug *may* vanish.  Also, consider tracking a point that looks "funny" to you.  Draw the orbit of a point which went appears to have crossed over that half plane, and see what it did.  Often funny behaviors expose themselves that way, both funny algorithm quirks and funny real-life behaviors.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica The effect *seems* to go away, if I make the stepsize a factor of 50(!) smaller. I haven't had time to test this properly, since the simulation is now taking a long time, even though I cut the number of particles by a factor of 10 and I have to go to bed now. **IF** the effects vanish at that small step size, I seriously question if RK does even do me any good in this case, or if I should switch back to Euler or Verlet-velocity integration.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica I did have a bug in my integration, so I updated the question to no longer include any mention of Runge-Kutta. But the initial question still remains.

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you get rid of the cool-looking initial plot and replace it with the new one, which *does* just look like two half planes?

Comment: @BenCrowell as explained in the comment above, I fixed an error in the integrator and the plot now *does* look like two half planes.

Comment: I'm thinking a symmetry argument could be sufficient here. Of course there is a mirror symmetry, but there is also a scale symmetry relating to velocities: if you scale the distance, of course the basin regions would need to scale as well; but this is equivalent to scaling down velocities; so that any velocity must proportionally match the eps-velocity basin picture in a way. The only figures that satisfy this invariance (plus some other constraints) ought to be planes (note how it doesn't change with scale). Particles (assuming 0 initial velocity o.c.) should never even leave their side ?

Comment: @Real Thank you for your helpful comment. Could you clarify what *eps* means in this context? And wouldn't your argument also work if we add a third body at the origin?

Comment: My simulations strongly suggest particles stay on their own side, regardless of initial conditions (with zero initial velocities ofc). This might imply there is some constant of motion forbidding passing over. The same, however, is not true for three fixed bodies in an equilateral triangle, some initial conditions allow a particle to hop from orbiting one body to another.

Comment: @Kasper I have experienced the same thing.[1] But since the Lagrangian doesn't have cyclic coordinates, I am not sure how to find some generalized momentum in this case.
---
[1]I wrote a small paper on the case of the equalateral triangle, where the case of the two bodies was glossed over. Since I am not working on a video series about the subject, I revisited this case and couldn't prove the fact of the two half planes.

Comment: Interestingly, the paths of the particles seem to ergodically fill regions that in elliptical coordinates correspond to $\mu < \mu(0)$ and $\nu < \nu(0)$. However, the Lagrangian in elliptical coordinates is not very enlightening either. This might be of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_three-body_problem

Comment: @Kasper Yours and **Real**s comments suggest to me, that one must find symmetries of the system (or generalized-coordinate transformations $q\rightarrow q^{'}$ such that the Lagragian is symmetric or even invariant) to find constants of motion, from which it the question could be answered. An application of Noethers Theorem.

Not sure, if it's ok to add this here. It is not supposed to be a discussion, merely the essence of what I researched after reading both of your comments.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration from looking at the paths of greatest descent? Plotting of the vector field $(\partial_x V, \partial_y V )$ seems to clearly show that a particle will not cross from one half-place to the other on its route to the potential minima.

Comment: On another note, plotting the basins of attraction for the n-th roots of unity lead generally to fractal structures, except for the case of $n=2$ (square roots), in which case you just have two half-planes. Possibly this is a similar effect.

Comment: @NiveaNutella after collision, is the test body removed from simulation? I ask because if not the body can end up colliding with the other too.

Comment: @lineage When a collision is detected, the particle gets removed and its initial position is colored in the corresponding color of the planet it collided with.

Comment: @NiveaNutella, how do you measure the error of the approximation of the masses _M_ stayng static? Wouldn't these two big masses starting at rest collide first?

Comment: @Daniel I don't. This problem is about a particle moving in a *static* gravitational field as stated in the title and in the NOTE directly after the question. If you wanted to view this as a simulation of two moving masses, read the first comment by Ben Crowell.

Comment: @NiveaNutella, I understood your assumptions; the problem is that - if you are doing Physics - your assumptions have to make sense at least in thought experiments.

Comment: @Daniel On the help page there is a list of topics one can ask about on this forum. This problem is (1) A actively researched area (from Euler, to Lagrange, to Jacobi and more recently Mathúna and Biscani&Izzo). Techniques used to solve problems of similar nature have found applications in quantum theory in the study of the $H_2^+$ Ion.(2) It is about Mathematics in the context of physics. (3) It's in the context of computational physics. If you think this question does not belong on the forum, please use the downvote button and flag the question.

Comment: What you have here is a continental divide.

Comment: Curiously, this phenomenon seems to hinge critically on the inverse-square nature of the force. Adding even the tiniest perturbation to the exponent of the distance in the expression for the force makes it untrue. That makes me wonder if there's a connection with the LRL vector

Comment: Fun problem. One issue is how to define a collision. I assume it is done operationally by having an "orbit trap" that is a small circle around the mass of some radius $r_{trap}$. However, the basin structure is sensitive to $r_{trap}$: as it goes to zero the boundaries become ever more convoluted and interleaved. In the point case collision trajectories lie on a 3D submanifold of the 4D phase space that is space-filling at least for $N>2$.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I had the sign of the inequality wrong, and in such case no conclusion can be reached from the inequality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good news is that your conjecture is true. The bad news is that my proof offers little insight. I'm not sure a small proof by some symmetry argument is possible, since it's not simply the symmetry of the setup that counts, the result is specific to inverse-square forces. Any perturbation to the exponent of the force leads to the particle skipping from side to side, generally behaving quite chaotically. This is reminiscent of the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector), I wouldn't be surprised if there is some correspondence.

Anyway, first off, I'm assuming $GM = m = 1$. By symmetry considerations, we can assume the motion happens in a plane, so we'll just use two coordinates $x$ and $y$. Now let's use [elliptical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system), of course placing the static masses at the foci $x = -a$ and $x = +a$

$$ x = a \cosh \mu \cos \nu ,\\ y = a \sinh \mu \sin \nu .$$

Working through the algebra (and with the help of Mathematica) our Lagrangian turns out to be

\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{L} &= \frac{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2}}  \\
& = \frac{a^2 (\cosh^2 \mu - \cos^2 \nu) (\dot{\mu}^2+\dot{\nu}^2)}{2}+\frac{1}{a} \frac{2 \cosh \mu}{\cosh^2 \mu - \cos^2 \nu} \\
&= a^2 u \frac{\dot{\mu}^2+\dot{\nu}^2}{2} + \frac{1}{a} \frac{2 \cosh \mu}{u}.
\end{align*}

For convenience, I have defined $u(\mu, \nu) = \cosh^2 \mu - \cos^2 \nu$. To formulate the Hamiltonian, we need the conjugate momenta

$$ p_\mu = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot\mu} = a^2 u \dot{\mu} \\ p_\nu = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot\nu} = a^2 u \dot{\nu}.$$

The Legendre transform yields

$$ \mathcal{H} = p_\mu \dot{\mu} + p_\nu \dot{\nu} - \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{u} \left( \frac{p_\mu^2 + p_\nu^2}{2a^2} + \frac{2 \cosh \mu}{a}\right).$$

As this Hamiltonian is time-independent, we can define a conserved energy $E$ (which will be negative in our case). At this point, I'm uncertain about how exactly the next step works, and how correct it is. I could be mistaken. Taking inspiration from [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/400/1/228/1069081), we introduce a new fictitious time coordinate $\tau$ satisfying

$$ d\tau = u dt ,$$

and a new Hamiltonian

$$ \mathcal{H}' = u(\mathcal{H} - E).$$

Taking partial derivatives we find an equivalent of Hamilton's equations

$$ -\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}'}{\partial q} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial q}(\mathcal{H}-E) - u \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial q} = u \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{dp}{d\tau} \\ 
\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}'}{\partial p} = u \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial q} = u \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{dq}{d\tau}, $$

where we used the fact that $\mathcal{H} = E$ on-shell in the second step of the first line. These equations allow us to solve the equations of motion in function of the fictitious time coordinate $\tau$. Given the implicit definition of $\tau$, based on the coordinates itself, this might not seem like it would help, but for this purpose qualitative arguments based on the general form of the Hamiltonian will suffice.

Substituting in everything, in our case the new Hamiltonian looks like

$$ \mathcal{H}' = \frac{p_\mu^2 + p_\nu^2}{2 a^2} - \frac{2 \cosh \mu}{a} - E \cosh^2 \mu + E \cos^2 \nu .$$

It turns out $\mu$ and $\nu$ completely decouple, and basically look like two harmonic oscillators (up to a coordinate transformation)! If the two oscillation periods are incommensurate, as they will be for generic initial conditions, the particle will ergodically fill the region it is energetically allowed inside, coming arbitrarily close to any point inside of it, including the massive bodies themselves. This agrees with my simulations, an example of which is pictured. Here the blue line shows the trajectory of the particle, and the green and orange lines are curves of respectively constant $\mu$ and $\nu$.

[image: Trajectory of test particle]

The part corresponding to $\nu$,

$$ \mathcal{H}_\nu' = \frac{p_\mu^2}{2a^2} - |E| \cos^2 \nu , $$

implies that $\cos^2 \nu > \cos^2 \nu_0$. Since the half-plane $x = 0$ corresponds to $\nu = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$, where the cosine achieves a minimum, this also proves that a particle starting with zero initial velocity will be confined to its own side.

Comment: So the movement of the particle is confined to the intersection of two ellipses?

Comment: @Eli I need $\mathcal{H}'$ to decouple the two coordinates. The equations of motion following from the normal Hamiltonian are very complex and coupled. As far as I can tell, the conclusion doesn't follow from a simple algebraic statement like $\mathcal{H} = E$. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @NiveaNutella Lines of constant $\mu$ (like the green one) are ellipses, but lines of constant $\nu$ (like the orange one) are hyperbolae.

Answer (score 2):

*finally*

In the following $G=M=d=1$.

The equipotentials look like

[image]

For a particle starting from rest, the contours also represent the level curves of the first constant of motion, total energy $E$. Each point on the contour represents a starting point for a trajectory. In addition, a trajectory can't leave the interior of the contour. Since the contours for $V\le-2$ (the "$\infty$" curve) don't cross over to the other plane, for trajectories in these regions with $|x|>0$, $E$ alone segregates the basins into different plains.

Now consider the second constant of motion,

$R=r_1^2r_2^2\dot{\theta_1}\dot{\theta_2}-2(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2)$

where the symbols are as as in-
[image]
As before we plot the level curves for this constant and see what they look like.
[image]
Each curve indicates a starting point of the trajectory.Each pair$(E,R)$ uniquely identifies the entire trajectory.

We observe that,$R$ seems to divide the starting points into 3 classes:

> $R\gtrless0$ corresponds to $x\lessgtr0$.

with $R=0$ implying $x=0 $ or $(y=0,0<|x|<1)$.
So trajectories starting in the right half-plane never enter the left as this requires a constant of motion to change sign. The $R=0$ with  $(y=0,0<|x|<1)$ is explicitly checked and found also to satisfy the above.

Since the equipotential bounds the trajectory on the right, the particle is doomed to meet its corresponding source of field.

---

The formula used for proving the correspondence was

$$
R(x_0,y_0,\dot{x}=0,\dot{y}=0)=
-2\left(\frac{x_0+1}{(x_0+1)^2+y_0^2}+\frac{x_0-1}{(x_0-1)^2+y_0^2}\right)
$$

---

## Earlier attempts

---

### 1

An object($|x_0|>0$) starting from rest, will only roam within the equipotential it was on at the beginning.
So for points within $\infty$ contour($V=-2$), the answer is in the affirmative: no crossing over to the other plane. This is evident from the direction of forces too.
[image]

Now consider the field plot for the direction of the horizontal component of force

[image]

Trivially, the answer is affirmative for $y_0=0$ as y component of force vanishes.

The red dots(numerically calculated) indicate the boundary (excluding $x=0$), 
 say $B$, where the horizontal component switches sign. Within this region, the particle always moves away from $x=0$.

**If** we could show that the particle never crosses B, then all such trajectories must terminate. Since the 
 only point of singularity for these would be the mass location so answer be in the affirmative for these points too.

Alas! this isn't true.

---

### 2

So instead,
**If** we can show that the particle never crosses $y=\pm m x$ where $m=y_0/x_0$ and $0<x<x_0$, the basins would indeed be half planes. This seems to be indicated by sims.

**work in progress**

To prove the this hypothesis, we''ll try the following program.

1. First we show that the force $F$ on $y=\pm mx$ always points into the region $mx>|y|$. As a result at least initially, the particle isn't going to cross.
2. Let energy $E(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$ and something else, $R(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$ be the 2 constants of motion.
3. We can eliminate $\dot{y}$ in $R$ using $E=E(x_0,y_0,0,0)=E_0$ to get $R(x,y,\dot{x})$.
4. For any trajectory, $R=R(x_0,y_0,0)=R_0$. Now comes the important part:

   > If the trajectory intersects $y=m x$ at another point $x'$, then $R'=R(x',m x',\dot{x'})=R_0$. We then analyze the behaviour of $R'-R_0 \forall 0<x'<x_0 ,-\infty<\dot{x'}<\infty $ hoping to find no real root.
5. A similar procedure for $y=-m x$ would bound the particle on the left while the equipotential already bounds it on the right.

The $R$ being used is
$R=r_1^2r_2^2\dot{\theta_1}\dot{\theta_2}-2(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2)$
where the parameters are as indicated in the main answer above.

Currently, this procedure seems to fail.
e.g. for $m=1, x_0=y_0=3$, here's what the plot is:

[image] 
(the blue plane is $R_0=R'$)
So for the following $x,\dot{x}$ values 
[image]

there seem to exist values $(x',\dot{x'})$ for which, the trajectory swivels back to the line.

However, we should note that the existence of a negative $\dot{x}$ can't alone imply crossing as some large value of ${\dot{y}}$ may still keep the trajectory inbound.

Comment: I've read about the constant of motion($R$) in the literature, but I could not find the symmetry to which it corresponds. Any ideas, or did you get it from somewhere?
(Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought every symmetry yields a Noether-Charge, which is a constant of motion. And every constant of motion corresponds to a symmetry..)

Comment: emabarassed to say I got it from wiki but the references check out: 1) E.T. Whittaker, *A treatise on the analytical dynamics of particles and rigid bodies* , pg 283 2) Coulson's paper,https://doi.org/10.1002%2Fqua.560010405

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Comment: as for the converse of Noether's theorem, given conserved charge what is the symmetry, it seems complicated. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24596/is-the-converse-of-noethers-first-theorem-true-every-conservation-law-has-a-sy

Comment: great question, by the way

Comment: Again, thanks for the reference. The book mentioned in my post (Integrable Systems in Celestial Mechanics) even though a good read, turned out not to cover particles with no initial velocity. And the question turned out to be much harder than I initially thought (as it does so often).

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the problem is to start a particle at rest at every point in the plane and track its trajectory until it hits one of the stationary masses.

The problem can be transformed to that of starting the particle *near* a stationary mass and looking for initial velocity vectors that result in the particle's trajectory reaching a point where the particle is momentarily stationary. One such counterexample is enough, if the stationary point is on the opposite half-plane from the starting point.

The stationary point could only be on an equipotential surface that corresponds to the particle's initial kinetic energy.  And, I think the particle must necessarily approach its ultimate stationary point in a direction normal to the equipotential surface, which might provide a useful further constraint.

I have done analogous searches: for gravitational slingshot trajectories.  The search was done using a genetic algorithm, and proceeded very rapidly. Because your problem is only 2D, you might be able to use a more direct technique like Newton's Method.

This approach might be able to disprove the two half-plane hypothesis, but it can't *prove* it.