# Why a symmetry, in Lagrangian field theory, should allow a boundary term?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, soft-question, definition, classical-field-theory

Following the discussion in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07038) (discussion around Eq. (3) in Page 4) and [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064) (discussion in Section 1.2.1 in page 10) given a field theory in some spacetime $(M,g)$ described by an action $I[\phi^i]$ written in terms of a Lagrangian $d$-form in the usual way: $$I[\phi^i]=\int_{M}{\cal L}[\phi^i]$$
a symmetry is defined as any variation $\delta \phi^i$ such that the action changes by a boundary term, or equivalently, the Lagrangian changes by a total derivative: $$\delta{\cal L}=d\Xi\Longleftrightarrow \delta I[\phi^i]=\int_{\partial M}\Xi.$$

**My question**: what is the motivation to define a symmetry like that allowing a boundary term? Why a symmetry is defined as a variation that might produce a boundary term, thereby giving $\delta I[\phi^i]=\int_{\partial M}\Xi$ instead of a variation that keeps the action invariant giving $\delta I[\phi^i]=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinitesimal off-shell transformation that preserves the action up to boundary terms is a so-called *quasisymmetry.* The main reason to consider quasisymmetries is that [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) also works for them: They also produce on-shell conservation laws. In fact they are the natural class to study in order to have a bijective correspondence with conservation laws, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451) Phys.SE post.