# Finding symmetry from conserved quantity (reversed Noether's theorem)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem

Is Noether's theorem reversible? For example, given some conserved quantity, can you find the underlying symmetry which leads to the conserved quantity?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28140/159456

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the converse of Noether's first theorem true: Every conservation law has a symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/)