# How does a charge or a Noether charge create a continuous symmetry?

Tags: charge, conservation-laws, symmetry, vector-fields, noethers-theorem

I recently searched up the definition for a more generalized definition of charge whether it be color charge or electric charge . And I found this but i fail to understand what this statement actually means :

> A charge is any generator of a continuous symmetry of the physical system under study. When a physical system has a symmetry of some sort, Noether's theorem implies the existence of a conserved current. The thing that "flows" in the current is the "charge", the charge is the generator of the (local) symmetry group. This charge is sometimes called the Noether charge.--- Source Wikipedia

Taking this statement " A charge is any generator of a continuous symmetry of the physical system under study."

What do continuous symmetry means and generator mean?
How does a charge create a continuous symmetry and how does it impact the physical system?

Comment: You should search up principle of least action and lagrangian first. Try to get your hands on David morins classical mechanics book.

Comment: Exactly what part of lagrangian mechanics can help on the understanding of this ?

Comment: [Maybe this helps you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0NYaO_OnH4&ab_channel=PhysicswithElliot)

Comment: Quote from which Wiki page?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(physics) - for your reference

Answer (score 2):

1. OP's question is related to the converse/inverse Noether's theorem, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. Let us for simplicity only consider the Hamiltonian formulation.
   In the Hamiltonian formulation a constant of motion/conserved quantity/charge $Q(q,p,t)$ is the generator of a [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_Q$, which in turn generates a finite continuous Hamiltonian [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)). The corresponding infinitesimal transformation is $$\delta z^I ~=~\epsilon\{z^I, Q\}, \qquad I~\in~\{1,\ldots, 2n\}, \qquad \delta t ~=~0,\tag{A}$$
   where $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter. One may show that this is a symmetry of the Hamiltonian action, cf. statement 3 in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69277/2451).