# When does conservation laws imply symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

It's commonly believed that symmetries imply conservation laws. I heard about sometimes the derivation of conservation laws from symmetry principles can be run in reverse, but I'm not quite sure when this happens, and why in general symmetry has an explanatory priority, rather than conservations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451