# What is the reason behind why energy must always be conserved, apart from observation?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, mass-energy, noethers-theorem

I know that we see in experiments (physical and thought) that energy is always transformed into something else, but what propels our universe to behave this way? What is happening at small levels that only allows conservation as a possible outcome and not destruction of energy?

**Update:** Based on a given answer stating that energy *is* mass, I should probably then expand this question into "Why must mass must always be conserved?"

Comment: Very philosophical question. We all know what time is, do we? (I don't think so, but all physics and more is build upon that.) If we agree to do so, there is something (has to do with Noether) that is necessarily preserved while time is passing.  By observation, this "something" is mass. Excuse me if I have added more confusion than information.

Comment: How do you *define* energy at the general level if not as that which is conserved through time translations by Noether's theorem?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Mass is the length of the energy-momentum four-vector. The mass of a system is not the sum of the masses of the parts (the length of a sum of vectors isn't of the sum the lengths) and since energy and momentum aren't conserved, neither is mass. So it isn't  conserved.

Comment: @Timaeus no te creo, can you give more detailed reasoning?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2690/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Mass is the length of the energy-momentum four-vector $\left((mc^2)^2=E^2-(\vec pc)^2)\right).$ Energy and momentum aren't conserved because when there is gravity, $0=\nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu}\neq\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}.$

Comment: @Timaeus I'm struggling to understand this.  Do you have some link from where I can get more understanding? Everything I have seen about that has either fainted into some brubble or jumped suddenly to a higher level without any explanation that I could have mentally followed.

Comment: Mass is a form of energy; mass alone is not conserved.  The Noether theorems, derived from analytical mechanics, tell us that conserved quantities come from symmetries: conservation of momentum comes from translational symmetry (homogeneity of space) ; conservation of angular momentum comes rotational symmetry (isotropy of space); and conservation of energy comes from a temporal symmetry (laws of mechanics do not change with time).  So that is the deeper meaning.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem

Comment: @GyroGearloose If you want a tutorial about what mass is, any book that covers Special Relativity in depth should go into it. If you want a tutorial about the lack of conservation of energy and momentum then any book that covers General Relativity in depth should go into it. The covsriant divergence of the Stress-Energy tensor is zero, but the divergence of the Stress-Energy tensor would give you conservation. But it's worse, energy and momentum don't even exist in General Relativity, only energy *density* and momentum *density* fields and there isn't a frame invariant way to add them up.

Comment: To my knowledge, it is pretty much a declare :The reason why energy conserved is: it doesn't matter when you measure Lagrange, it is always same. And since there is no reasons (that I know) for why it is always same, so it is a declare. (and even if there is one reason, you can keep asking why to that reason, and so on. Eventually, there must be a starting point; therefore, this is pretty much a declare.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer saying that energy was mass was incorrect. And neither is conserved, and neither is even additive.

In General Relativity you have a Stress-Energy energy tensor. It has ten independent components in any frame. And you can try to extract one of them to be the energy density and three others to give you the components of the momentum density. But that decomposition is *locally* frame dependent. And even if you did that, you only get a density at every point and since a surface of simultaneity depends on a *global* frame (which don't always exist and aren't unique when they do exist) trying to add up those densities at different points on a surface of "same time" to get a total energy and a total momentum is hopeless generally.

So there isn't an energy of the universe. And there isn't a momentum of the universe. And even if there were, they could be infinite. And even if it when they are finite, then the mass would satisfy $$(mc^2)^2=E^2-(\vec p c)^2$$ and the mass of the universe would **not** equal the sum of the masses of the parts. And since the energy and momentum would change over time, the mass usually changes over time.