# Can we deduce the conservation of mass in non-relativist physics or is it just an experimental fact?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mass, conservation-laws, classical-field-theory

It is a well-known fact that mass by itself is not conserved (since, for example, a particle can annihilate with its antiparticle). However, in classical physics, and as long as there is no physical process of annihilation/creation of matter with mass, we have an "approximate conservation law" for mass (i.e. outside the processes of nuclear physics or quantum mechanics, we have no major violations of "mass conservation" in non-relativistic/non-quantum physics).

Furthermore, in classical mechanics, Noether's theorem explains under what circumstances the other conservation laws appear. However, it does not seem possible to use Noether's theorem to deduce that under the type of restricted processes of non-nuclear physics mass must be conserved. I wonder whether this implies that the conservation of mass in certain processes cannot be deduced from more general principles, and we must simply accept it as an irreducible and unexplained empirical observation.

---

One possibility is to start from a Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L} = f(\rho,u^\alpha,x^\alpha)$ to obtain the energy-stress tensor for a free-preasure "fluid":

$$T^{\alpha\beta} = \rho u^\alpha u^\beta $$

then:

$$\frac{\partial T^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^\alpha} \approx \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial(\rho c)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial(\rho v_x)}{\partial x} + \dots + \frac{\partial(\rho v_z)}{\partial z} = 0$$

which is precisely the continuity equation that expresses the conservation of mass.

Comment: The only process by which mass can change in classical physics is by traversing the boundary of the system - this is described by the continuity equation. [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass) is rather interesting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the symmetry which is responsible for conservation of mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2690/)

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, we don't deduce things in physics. We experiment and observe, and adjust our mathematical models accordingly. All deduction from math is suspect when applied to physics. Mathematical objects are products of the human imagination, not things present in reality. When we have a well-tested correspondence between the math and the physics, we consider the math trustworthy for practical purposes, but we keep checking as we improve experimental technique.

Mass conservation is an assumption of classical physics. It comes from commonsense observation: even pre-physics, mass was what a balance measured, and that implicitly assumed mass conservation.

Perfectly good math misapplied to physics can [lead to nonsense.](https://xkcd.com/804/) And pretending to teach physics when all you're teaching is math can lead to [profound ignorance of physics.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIhk9eKOLzQ)